# Iterating through array in mysql table column php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a MySQL table, and in one of the fields I have a list of colors that looks like this

```
'red','blue','green','yellow','purple','orange','black'
```

I need to iterate through these colors to use them individually, but I can't figure it out.

I'm currently using a `foreach` loop but I'm getting this error - `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
foreach($product['colors'] as $color) { 
    echo '<a href="javascript:color(\'' . $color . '\');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/' . $color . '.jpg" title="' . ucfirst($color) . '" /></a>'; 
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explode them so, items are separated using the `,` as delimeter before foreach,

```
$product['colors'] = explode(',' ,$product['colors']);
```

and, trim out extra `'` while displaying inside foreach

```
$color = trim($color, "'");
```